# Ventura hangs intermittently on external monitor clamshell mode

Tags: macbook-pro, display, ventura

Ever since I upgraded my MacBook Pro 16 inch to Ventura it hangs intermittently when being used on external monitor in clamshell mode. I have to open the laptop and hard restart.

The problem becomes more prominent when it goes into to sleep mode. It comes up, goes to login screen and then hangs.

Is anybody else facing this problem and is there any setting as workaround till the fix?

Answer (score 1):

I have observed that my external monitor was connected via USB C and Display Port. For the past few days I have changed to HDMI and the problem does not seem to be happening, however my monitor refresh rate has now dropped to 60 Hz from 100Hz...

Seems it is an issue with Mac OS Ventura with direct USB C port external display connectivity.